# Mule ftp inbound doesn't have sizeCheckWaitTime property

Tags: java, ftp, mule, mule-studio

I had a problem with the fileAge property, that I solved by using the sizeCheckWaitTime property. However, I can only do that with the sftp inbound, because the ftp inbound doesn't have the sizeCheckWaitTime property. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either:

- use a [service override](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+a+Transport#ConfiguringaTransport-overrides) to change the [message receiver](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/transports/ftp/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/ftp/FtpMessageReceiver.java) to change the call to [connector.validateFile(file)](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/transports/ftp/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/ftp/FtpMessageReceiver.java#L295) for your own needs.
- instantiate our own inherited class of the [connector](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/transports/ftp/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/ftp/FtpConnector.java) using custom-connector, overridding the method [validateFile(FTPFile file)](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/transports/ftp/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/ftp/FtpConnector.java#L677) with your own needs.

Comment: Thanks Victor! Great book, BTW.